# Custom directive is not working for angular 6:

Tags: angular6

Changing backgound color of the paragraph tag using custom directive not working for angular 6 .

@CustomDirective

```
import { Directive,ElementRef,HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appSteps]'
})
export class StepsDirective {

  constructor(private elementref: ElementRef){ }

  @HostListener('mouseenter')onmouseenter()
  {
    this.elementref.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
  
   }

  @HostListener('mouseleave')onmouseleave()
  {
    this.elementref.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'null';
  }
}
```

@ModuleCreated : Added my directive here and using this module in appmodule.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {StepsDirective}  from '../steps.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
    
  ],
  declarations: [StepsDirective]
})
export class StartModule { }
```

@AppComponent.html-Hosting my custom directive on

tag

```
<p appSteps>My Hero Academia</p>
```

@app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Signup_Component } from './signup/signup.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { StartModule } from './start/start.module'; *Module created 

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Signup_Component, 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    StartModule,

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should first export the module that you declare your directive in then import it any where you want to use

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule

  ],
  exports:[StepsDirective]
  declarations: [StepsDirective]
})
export class StartModule { }
```